# How to know that flowable throws exception in flow

Tags: activiti, flowable

I am using the flowable and wanted to know how flowable gives or how we know the flowable giving an error or exception. I am running the flowable docker image, so on the terminal, we come to know that exception occurs, but flowable UI does not show any message or inform that exception occurred.